# CMake build FMT and dependent libraries during configuration stage

Tags: cmake, fmt, spdlog, cmake-language, cmake-custom-command

For couple of days I've tried to build FMT and SPDLOG with FMT as external library during configuration phase of CMake.

BuildFmt.cmake:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  fmt
  OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
  URL "file://${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/fmt-10.1.1.tar.gz"
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(fmt)
if(NOT fmt_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(fmt)
endif()

execute_process(OUTPUT_QUIET
  COMMAND cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DFMT_TEST=OFF ${fmt_SOURCE_DIR}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${fmt_BINARY_DIR}"
  RESULT_VARIABLE FMT_RESULT)

execute_process(OUTPUT_QUIET
  COMMAND make
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${fmt_BINARY_DIR}"
  RESULT_VARIABLE FMT_RESULT)

set(FMT_BUILT ON CACHE BOOL "FMT is built" FORCE)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${fmt_BINARY_DIR}")
```

BuildSpdLog.cmake:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  spdlog
  OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE
  URL "file://${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/spdlog-1.12.0.tar.gz"
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(spdlog)
if(NOT spdlog_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(spdlog)
endif()
  
execute_process(
  COMMAND cmake -DSPDLOG_BUILD_SHARED=ON -DSPDLOG_BUILD_PIC=ON -DSPDLOG_BUILD_EXAMPLE=OFF -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL=ON ${spdlog_SOURCE_DIR}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${spdlog_BINARY_DIR}"
  RESULT_VARIABLE SPDLOG_RESULT)

execute_process(
  COMMAND make
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${spdlog_BINARY_DIR}"
  RESULT_VARIABLE SPDLOG_RESULT)

set(SPDLOG_BUILT ON CACHE BOOL "SPDLOG is built" FORCE)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${spdlog_BINARY_DIR}")
add_subdirectory(${spdlog_SOURCE_DIR} ${spdlog_BINARY_DIR})
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.7)

project("test")

add_compile_definitions(SPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

include(BuildFmt)
include(BuildSpdLog)

find_package(fmt REQUIRED CONFIG)

add_executable(my_importer main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_importer fmt::fmt)
```

main.cpp (just to have one including FMT)

```
#include<fmt/format.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Build is OK, but when I do `ldd` I see system's FMT is linked:

```
nikola@notebook ~/projects/2m/cmake_test/build $ ldd ./_deps/spdlog-build/libspdlog.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff1a948000)
libfmt.so.9 => /usr/lib64/libfmt.so.9 (0x00007f94489e2000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9448782000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f94486a2000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f944867e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f94484ab000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9448ab7000)
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. In case I add dependenccy SPDLOG to main, during `make`, I see that SPDLOG is rebuild and it links to correct `libfmt.so`:

```
nikola@notebook ~/projects/cmake_test/build $ make
[ 11%] Building CXX object _deps/spdlog-build/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/spdlog.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object _deps/spdlog-build/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/stdout_sinks.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object _deps/spdlog-build/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/color_sinks.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object _deps/spdlog-build/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/file_sinks.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object _deps/spdlog-build/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/async.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object _deps/spdlog-build/CMakeFiles/spdlog.dir/src/cfg.cpp.o
[ 77%] Linking CXX shared library libspdlog.so
[ 77%] Built target spdlog
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/2m_importer.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable 2m_importer
[100%] Built target 2m_importer
nikola@notebook ~/projects/2m/cmake_test/build $ ldd ./_deps/spdlog-build/libspdlog.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe279d000)
    libfmt.so.10 => /home/nikola/projects/2m/cmake_test/build/_deps/fmt-build/libfmt.so.10 (0x00007f882ee5c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f882ebd7000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f882eaf7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f882ead3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f882e900000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f882eef3000)
```

My knowledge of CMake is very basic, so it is possible I am trying to do something very stupid. I tried with ExternalProject's  also but no luck.

Comment: `find_package` looks for **installed** library, not for the one which is just built.

Comment: Indeed, but it is also used by SPDLOG's CMakeLists to search for FMT. This is why I tried also `find_package(fmt REQUIRED CONFIG)` prior building SPDLOG. I am unsure how to "order" SPDLOG to find proper FMT - shall I install FMT somewhere first using `CMAKE_PREFIX_INSTALL`?

Answer (score 0):

After another round of trying and putting traces I have ended up with adding:

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/lib64/cmake
```

when building SPDLOG. Also, I've altered `make` command to `make install`.

Suggestion from @Tsyvarev give me a hint.